# Get email where values are same in duplicate JSON Object in Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I have one array of JSON object.

```
[{ Email: 'aa@gmail.com', status: 'Success' }
{ Email: 'bb@gmail.COM', status: 'Fail' }
{ Email: 'aa@gmail.COM', status: 'Fail' }
{ Email: 'cc@gmail.com', status: 'Success' }]
```

Now I want list of Email  that have different value in status with same Email.
from above example I can expect email `aa@gmail.com` because at first position `aa@gmail.com` have value `Success` and at third position `aa@gmail.com` have value `Fail`.

How can achieve that in Java Script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this code will work, but it's not the right way to do it - when you assign the values you need to check if they already exist and if so put it in an array, that will be easier.

```js
var mail = [{ Email: 'aa@gmail.com', status: 'Success' }
               { Email: 'bb@gmail.COM', status: 'Fail' }
               { Email: 'aa@gmail.COM', status: 'Fail' }
               { Email: 'cc@gmail.com', status: 'Success' }]; 

    var emails = mails.map(mail => mail.Email);
    var emailChecker = [];
    var emailDetectedTwice = [];

    for(var i = 0; i<=emails.length-1; i++){
        if(!emailChecker.includes(emails[i].toLowerCase())){
            emailChecker.push(emails[i])
        } else {
            emailDetectedTwice.push(emails[i])
        }
    }

    console.log(emailDetectedTwice);
```